# Saving gametime in Playerprefs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm about to add a gametime and save it Playerprefs. I'm putting it in the Update() but my concern is, will it have a big impact if I fetch and add value in Playerprefs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will make a huge impact on performance.
Don't perform read write operations in `Update`.

Store time as local variable, fetch it in `Start`
and save it in those methods

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
```

Answer (score 2):

It could have a non negligeable impact on performance.

But there's no need to update it every frame, best case should be to retrieve the value when you start playing, update the buffered value in a Monobehavior, and then saving it in the Playerprefs on specific events (player died, player paused the game, player quit the game, ...).

Keep in mind that altering playerprefs is extremely easy, so don't put data that's too sensitive in it.